# Processor heap read and prefetch

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

So i'm trying to figure out how heap reading can probably slow down processor capabilities with prefetching and it's only theoretical question so in example i use some C-like wonder-language.

So let's suppose we have some heap of 120 bytes and it's have some memory in use by a program.
[0...19, /* FREE */, 40-79, /* FREE TILL THE END (119) */]
and i have some structs with magically aligned by memory of 20 bytes

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct magic_struct {
   long long int foo[3];
   short int bar;
};

typedef MagicStruct struct magic_struct;

void read_magic_struct(MagicStruct* buzz) {
   // Some code to read struct
} 

int main(void) {
   MagicStruct *str1 = malloc(sizeof(MagicStruct));
   MagicStruct *str2 = malloc(sizeof(MagicStruct));

   read_magic_struct(str1);
   read_magic_struct(str2);
   
   free(str1);
   free(str2);
}
```

So let's suppose that our processor fetches cacheline of 40 bytes,
it means with our current memory representation processor can't prefetch str2 while reading str1 so it will be slow down in program execution? How do structs get allocated if there was an empty memory buffer or first empty memory chunk would be 40 bytes along? Would a processor hit to the cache misses if structs` size would be 50 bytes? Does some mechanism decides where and when allocate memory on heap?

Comment: Unless you have actual evidence that such location in memory is causing a problem with the performance of your application, you are ***WAAAAAY*** overthinking this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! A bigger version below helped me actually, but you are right too, i'm super overthinking and without actual problem with app the question doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does some mechanism decides where and when allocate memory on heap?

The mechanism that decides where memory is allocated on the heap is a piece of code called "memory allocator" - a part of the C runtime library - and it doesn't care much about prefetching or anything like that. Most memory allocators do their best to keep "related" allocations "close together", but it's only on a best-effort basis. So you can't really assume anything about how far away those two allocations are.

> How do structs get allocated if there was an empty memory buffer or first empty memory chunk would be 40 bytes along?

In any way that is possible: you can't know until you read the source code of the memory allocator used by the C runtime library on your system (e.g. glibc on most Linux systems). It's totally arbitrary and in general you can't predict how those structs will get allocated. And also in real life heap doesn't have to be contiguous, i.e. heap doesn't have to be a single big memory block, it will usually be many memory blocks, with gaps between them.

> So let's suppose that our processor fetches cacheline of 40 bytes, it means with our current memory representation processor can't prefetch str2 while reading str1 so it will be slow down in program execution?

Assuming the heap layout you proposed, the only valid statement is as follows: *the cacheline containing `str1` does not contain `str2`*. That's all you can say, and no more. It tells you nothing about prefetch, because prefetch has to do with fetching *other* cachelines ahead of time, before they are needed.

I think you're misusing the term "prefetch", because the processor only exchanges data with memory in terms of complete cachelines. Prefetch does not mean that when fetching a single cacheline some other useful data was also inside that cacheline. We call this cache coherency, and it's a property of how you lay out data in your program. If you need such fine control, you need to write your own memory allocator (even if it's simple).

Prefetch means that the processor has a system that monitors the cachelines being fetched, and *anticipates* the need for another cacheline, and fetches it before you use it. Prefetch can be triggered by explicit prefetch machine instructions, if you want to control it to such an extent, or it can be triggered by the prefetch algorithms implemented in the processor. Modern processors are **extremely good** at detecting *sequential access* that's contiguous or even separated by repeating gaps.

---

It's certainly good to ponder such things, but you have to understand that processors are pretty darn good, and if you think that prefetch may be your problem, you have to have some very good argument why it is so, and normally you'd need actual measurements. Talking about optimizing prefetch without having measurements that show that the processor is waiting for cachelines to come in from memory is absolutely foolish and a waste of time. So, in practical terms, if you'll want to explore this using real prefetch on real processors (as opposed to imaginary stuff), you'll have to install e.g. Intel VTune Profiler, or use Valgrind's cachegrind (on linux), run your program under those tools, then be able to interpret the results, pinpoint problems, address them by changing data layout or using explicit prefetch machine commands (or compiler intrinsic instructioins), and then be able to validate your solution by seeing improved cache hit rates. And ideally this should be automated so you won't have performance regressions, i.e. you'd run all this instrumentation and result interpretation as scripts under the continous integration system, so that you know that you won't accidentally break things. But this takes *lots* of work, and if you're starting from scratch (a new project), assuming that you were minimally fluent in scripting, CI systems, and C, then it'd still take potentially hundreds of hours to fully set up and shake down to be trustworthy. The guiding principle is:

**Lack of measurement is prima-facie evidence that you don't care about the result**

In other words, if you actually *care* about some aspect of performance, then the only way to show such care is to measure it, and have those measurements be a part of the normal workflow, i.e. that once they were set up, you don't even worry about them - you check in some new code, and if you broke performance, the performance tests will fail, and you'll have to fix it before you're allowed to merge. That's how it's normally done in an environment where that matters. Otherwise, the only interpretation is that you *cannot be* caring, since without automated measurements it is almost certain that some "minor" code change will affect performance and yet will slip unnoticed. Once you're told this, there's no going back, sorry :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It helped me to fill some gaps